# How to Ignore the error in querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function on my `javascript` with `querySelector` when I clicked the `Logout button` the `querySelector` throws an error. How do I ignore this error? Because It blocks my `function Logout()`.

Here's my `querySelector` function

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    parent[i].onclick = (e) => {
        const current_child = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.items-title').innerText;
        swal.fire({
            html: "Loading..",
            timer: 1000,
            icon: "info",
            timerProgressBar: true,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            showCancelButton: false,
            didOpen: () => {
                timerInterval = setInterval(() => { }, 100)
            },
            willClose: () => {
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
            }
        }).then(() => {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Shop/Results",
                data: {
                    result: current_child,
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#result").html(result);
                    $(".false").html(result);
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Here's my HTML logout:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link first changing-color">@ViewBag.username</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link first changing-color" id="search"><i class="fal fa-search"></i></a>
  <select class="form-control" id="search-bar" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
    <option selected></option>
  </select>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link first changing-color" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Wishlist"><i class="fal fa-heart"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link first changing-color" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Cart"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link first changing-color">₱@ViewBag.savings</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <form asp-action="Logout" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" method="post" id="logout">
    <a class="nav-link first changing-color" onclick="logout()">LOGOUT</a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Here's my HTML to use `querySelector`

```html
<div class="image-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <div class="wrapper-title">
          SHOP
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="wrapper-nav">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
            <div class="container">
              <button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin: auto;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#shopbar" aria-controls="shopbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="shopbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="unca">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th rowspan="2"></th>
                          <th class="items-title">UNCATEGORIZED</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>@ViewBag.total_items ITEMS</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed some of my `<li>`

Comment: "throws an error" — What error?

Comment: "How do I ignore this error?" — Since you appear to need the return value later, what good will ignoring it do? That just moves the error away from the problem and makes it harder to fix.

Comment: `e.currentTarget.querySelector(...) is null` This is the error that i wanted to ignore

Comment: Please see [mcve].  Only include the relevant code, eg is the SWAL relevant to the problem?  Probably not because it's after the error line.  The "logout" html seems to be also irrelevant.

Comment: Your code, as provided, appears to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/9gzpfwm8/).  Please add a *snippet* to your code ([edit] and click `[<>]`) with enough html (not razor) and js to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: ```e.currentTarget.querySelector(...) is null``` the element you are trying to access doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the table containing the relevant class can be empty in which case the error shows up.
To prevent the error from happening, check if any results are being returned. The error occurs because you're trying to get the `innerText` of a non-existing element.

I have renamed the class in the `th` to simulate an empty table.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
  parent[i].onclick = (e) => {
    // const current_child = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.items-title').innerText;
    
    // Check if querySelector returns any results
    if (e.currentTarget.querySelector('.items-title')) {
      const current_child = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.items-title').innerText;
    }
    // ... other code
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <div class="wrapper-title">
          SHOP
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="wrapper-nav">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
            <div class="container">
              <button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin: auto;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#shopbar" aria-controls="shopbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="shopbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="unca">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th rowspan="2"></th>
                          <!-- class is renamed -->
                          <th class="items--title">UNCATEGORIZED</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>@ViewBag.total_items ITEMS</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```